# NAs produced by own function - Convert "1,22B" or "100,00MIO" to "1220" and "100" Mio

Tags: r, type-conversion

My situation looks like this:

B = Billion, M = Million

```
df_example <- c("5,14B", "7,4B", "65,12M", "992,3M", "1,2B")
is.character(df_example)
> TRUE

# Function for converting

converting_mio_bio <- function(x) {
  if (str_contains(x, "B")) {
    x <- x %>% str_replace_all(",",".")
    x <- x %>% str_remove_all("B")
    x <- x %>% as.numeric()
    x <- x * 1000
  }
  else {
    x <- x %>% str_replace_all(",",".")
    x <- x %>% str_remove_all("M") 
    x <- x %>% as.numeric()
  }
  print(x)
}

# Applying function 

converting_mio_bio(df_example)
```

```
> converting_mio_bio(df_example) [1] 5140 7400 NA NA 1200 Warning message: In x %>% as.numeric() : NAs introduced by coercion>
```

This I get as result. Am not sure why. I know that it appears if there "," in the character or letters, but both should be fixed with the function. Can somebody tell me why this happens?

Thank you,

NAs produced by transforming character to numeric

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
chartr(",", ".", df_example) %>% 
  str_replace_all(setNames(c("e0", "e3"), c("M", "B"))) %>%
  as.numeric
```

-output

```
[1] 5140.00 7400.00   65.12  992.30 1200.00
```

---

Or similar approach in `base R`

```
chartr(",", ".", df_example) |> 
  gsub("M", "e0", x = _) |> 
  gsub("B", "e3", x = _) |> 
  as.numeric()
[1] 5140.00 7400.00   65.12  992.30 1200.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ex` in the Note at the end (we have renamed it since the name in the question suggests it is a data frame and it is actually a character vector) we use `gsubfn` to perform the indicated replacements.

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn(".", list("," = ".", B = "e9", M = "e6", K = "e3"), ex) |>
  as.numeric()
```

giving:

```
[1] 5.140e+09 7.400e+09 6.512e+07 9.923e+08 1.200e+09
```

### Note

```
ex <- c("5,14B", "7,4B", "65,12M", "992,3M", "1,2B")
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R

```
with(read.table(text=gsub("([MB])", " \\1", df_example), dec=','), V1*c(B=1000, M=1)[V2])
      B       B       M       M       B 
5140.00 7400.00   65.12  992.30 1200.00
```